# What is the word to describe a bird organizing its feathers?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, animals

Which verb most accurately and commonly describes a bird's daily behavior to make its feathers clean and organized.

- "organize" its feathers
- "brush" its feathers
- "clean" its feathers?

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic question, new user.  Just for your information, we have a special tag for this - **SWR**.   The site is famous for it!

Comment: as is 'to plume'

Answer (score 49):

The verb is ***[to preen](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/preen):***

> [ I or T ] If a bird preens or preens itself, it cleans and arranges its feathers using its beak.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

[image]

*preening macaw parrot*

From (blog.parrotessentials.co.uk)

Comment: A question. An answer.  This mustn't be the internet.

Comment: undeleted now ?

Comment: @lbf - apparently so, not by myself, though.

Comment: That is a great word

Answer (score 3):

To **preen** is the *primo* answer.  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/149937?rskey=arlkj3&result=3#eid) provided by @user240918

> intransitive. Of a bird: to tend its feathers with its beak,
>   arranging, cleaning, and generally maintaining them.

consideration to alternatives:

to **plume**   [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/146090?rskey=uFzFw8&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> b. Of a bird: to preen or trim (the feathers or wings). Also fig.
>   (frequently with the suggestion of preparation for something, as a
>   bird preens prior to flight).

As in:

> 1998   Anchorage (Alaska) Daily News (Nexis)   Delap admired the bird
>   as it clambered out on the ice and plumed its feathers ...

to **groom** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/81721?rskey=9VuNQv&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> transitive. Of an animal: to clean the skin, hair, etc., of (another
>   of its family or group). Also reflexive: to clean and tidy itself.

As in:  Social Psychology [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=x-u5Mp2sJssC&lpg=PA94&dq=birds%20grooming&pg=PA94#v=onepage&q=birds%20grooming&f=false)

> If all birds in an interacting population were to operate on a rule of
>   uncontingent altruism, things would go well for them; each individual
>   would sometimes bear the costs of grooming and sometimes enjoy the
>   benefits of being **groomed**.

Comment: Why discount ***preen***?  It is the primo answer...

Comment: @Jim I agree! 46 upvotes ... then it's deleted!

Comment: Oh!   I see. Was on my phone so didn’t see the deleted answer.  :-). I have voted to undelete.